# Validation of nested resource fails on build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building instances of a model in another model controller. All seems to work fine, child instances are well created with the parent id but as soon as I add validations for parent_id in this resource, the instance is no longer valid. Any idea what I'm missing ?

Mission model:

```
class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :planned_times
    validates :code,            presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :days_sold, presence: true
end
```

PlannedTime model:

```
class PlannedTime < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :mission
    validates :date,        presence: true
    validates :mission_id,  presence: true # this is the validation which causes problem
end
```

Mission controller:

```
class MissionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @mission = Mission.new(mission_params)
    week_nums = params[:weeks].split(/[\s]*[,;\-:\/+][\s]*/).uniq
    year = params[:year].to_i
    week_nums.each do |week_num|
      date = Date.commercial(params[:year].to_i,week_num.to_i)
      @mission.planned_times.build(date: date)
    end

    if @mission.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Mission added"
    end
  end



  private

    def mission_params
      params.require(:mission).permit(:code, :days_sold)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So validating the presence of associations is a little tricky. In your case you're putting the `mission_id` validator on the child association but rails runs the validation on `planned_time` before it saves the `mission` so it will fail because `mission_id` is still `nil`. Also, by putting the validation on `planned_time` it'll mean that that validation won't run if you never `mission.planned_items.build` because the associated `planned_time` won't exist and therefore not run its validations.

With minimal changes to your code or validation logic you can get it to work like this:

```
class PlannedTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mission
  validates :mission_id, presence: { if: ->(p) { p.mission.nil? } }
end
```

This part `presence: { if: ->(p) { p.mission.nil? } }` will check if there is a `mission` object present (albeit without an `id` yet) and if there is no mission object the validation will fail. So good, now we know we can't create a `planned_time` without its parent `mission` object present. But this says nothing about the `mission` requiring the `planned_time` to be created. If this is what you want then that's the solution. Although I'm left wondering if you really wanted it the other way around where you want to make sure a `mission` is always created along with its `planned_time`?

Comment: Ok I understand it better now. Thank you. I want to create a mission with or without planned_time but a planned_time should always have a mission.